# ToolTip - Title not working in IE 6

Tags: html, css, xhtml, dhtml

I am using a dropdown, which having the width of 100px. But the content with in that dropdown is more than that - its not visible to the user, so i go for title (ToolTip in html). Its not working in IE 6..

What is the alternative method for this.. mouseover event is also not working in . Please help and clarify the bug

```
<select>
    <option>-</option>
    <option  title="Alpha">a</option>
    <option  title="Beta">b</option>
    <option  title="Complex">c</option>
    <option  title="Durpal">d</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You should post your code or, at least, the link to the page you're trying to build.

Answer (score 1):

I think the attribute that IE used for that purpouse was "alt" instead of "title".

Comment: there is no "alt" attribute for <option> - dropdown

Comment: yeah, like if the IE cared about what attributes are in the standard ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you are saying is there are options within your select which have a text that overflow past the edge of the select. If this is the case there isn't really an easy way to fix it (other than increasing the size of the drop down list). You may want to look into a third party component which will emulate a drop down list. Using one of these, the area which drops down isn't tied to the select element, so that area can be larger.

See this for an example

http://jquery.sanchezsalvador.com/samples/example.htm

Comment: Is there any way to solve this with out jquery, because i dont have any knowledge in jquery

Comment: Make your drop down wider, or perhaps rig a javascript solution to show the selected value in a dom element somewhere else on the page.